# Missing events on UWP

Tags: c#, wpf, events, uwp

Im creating custom control on uwp (from wpf) and I`ve missed several events, such like:

1. OnTemplateChanged
2. OnRender
3. OnRenderSizeChanged

Where are them? Or can I replace them with other handlers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No equivalent, you may subscribe to changes of the `Template` property, e.g. by a Binding.
2. No equivalent, there's nothing like DrawingVisual/DrawContext in UWP.
3. [`FrameworkElement.SizeChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.sizechanged)